# Erlang debugger not working

Tags: erlang

When I started the erlang debugger:start(). in shell on freebsd 10.3 vm, I got the following error message:

```
{error,{undef,[{wx,new,[],[]},
      {dbg_wx_mon,init,3,[{file,"dbg_wx_mon.erl"},{line,114}]}]}}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the `erlang-wx` port installed? https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/ports.cgi?query=erlang-wx&stype=name

Comment: As the Romans said:Who debugs the debuggers? ;)

Answer (score 1):

The debugger gui uses WxWidget library. It is not included in the distribution (except maybe for windows installation):

> wxWidgets -- Toolkit for GUI applications. Required for building the
>   wx application. At least version 3.0 of wxWidgets is required.
>
> Download from http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxwindows/files/3.0.0/
>   or get it from GitHub: https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets
>
> Further instructions on wxWidgets, read Building with wxErlang.
>
> (http://erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL.html#Advanced-configuration-and-build-of-ErlangOTP_Building_Building-with-wxErlang)